# Python Pillow Library Error : PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, pycharm, runtime-error, python-imaging-library

```
"E:\Extras and Soft\the coder(codes)\PYCharm\sept 2020\scripting in python (course time)\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "E:/Extras and Soft/the coder(codes)/PYCharm/sept 2020/scripting in python (course time)/img2png.py"

**Enter the image directory : pokedesk/
Enter the output directory : pokedesk/new_desk/
1 file done**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Extras and Soft/the coder(codes)/PYCharm/sept 2020/scripting in python (course time)/img2png.py", line 16, in <module>
    img = Image.open(f'{image_folder}{filename}')
  File "E:\Extras and Soft\the coder(codes)\PYCharm\sept 2020\scripting in python (course time)\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2878, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'pokedesk/new_desk'
1 file done

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is the error named `Permission Error` happening after the processing of the 2 files with the PILLOW library. Now there were 4 files I wanted to convert but I get two of them done . I will leave you with the screenshot of the code and the error too . Thanks in advance!

My code:

```py
import os
from PIL import Image
# image_folder = sys.argv[1]
# output_folder = sys.argv[2]
image_folder = input("Enter the image directory : ")
output_folder = input("Enter the output directory : ")

# print(image_folder)
# print(output_folder)

if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
    os.makedirs(output_folder)

for filename in os.listdir(image_folder):

    img = Image.open(f'{image_folder}{filename}')

    clean_name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]

    img.save(f'{output_folder}{clean_name}.png', 'png')

    print('1 file done')
```

The error that I got:
[image: The error that I got]

Comment: could you upload your tree directory?

Comment: some times it happens when you already open the file using another application installed in your PC (image viewer, photos)

Comment: also try with  `img = Image.open(r'{image_folder}{filename}')`

Comment: fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '{image_folder}{filename}'

Its returning this after using a raw string

Answer (score 0):

try this:
img = Image.open(f'{image_folder}{filename}','wb')

Comment: Raise ValueError("bad mode %r" % mode)
ValueError: bad mode 'wb'

Now its giving a ValueError.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this syntax

```py
with Image.open(f'{image_folder}{filename}') as img:
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you explain how using a context manger would help solve the problem?